# I'm stuck with a certain task about lists and appending integers and strings

Tags: python, string

I have been set 5 tasks to do 4 of which I have done but the 5th is a struggle these are the tasks:

1. Create a text file and write a list of 10 English words in it.
2. Develop the part of your program that reads in the words from this text file and chooses one at random.
3. Develop the part of the program that substitutes every letter in the word for the corresponding number in the alphabet. For instance CAT would become 3, 1, 20.
4. Develop the part of the program that allows the user to enter a number and then the letter that they think it represents. The program should tell them if it is right or wrong and then display the word with the correct substitutions. For instance if the user enters A for 1 then it should say “yes” or similar and then display 3, A, 20.
5. Develop the part of the program that continues this until the user has guessed the whole word correctly.

I have done up to 4 but number 5 Im struggling with my code is this:

```
#Import Section
import random
import csv
import math

#Start Variables
Random_Words = []
alph = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p',     'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]
word_2 = []

#Foundation Code (List of words)
words = open('List_Words.txt') 
first_10 = []
for line in words:
    Random_Words.append(line[:-1])

#Making the random word 
word = random.choice(Random_Words)
word = list(word)

#Making the random word into an alphabetical numeral
for character in word:
    i = 0 
    while i < 26:
        if character == alph[i]:
            word_2.append(num[i])
        i = i + 1

#print word
#print Random_word
print word_2    

#Letting the person guess the word/ letter   
guess_number = int(raw_input("choose a number:  "))
guess_letter = raw_input("choose a letter:  ")

i = word.index(guess_letter)
if word_2[i] == guess_number:
    print "Correct"

else:
    print "Nope"
```

Comment: Wrap the guessing logic into a [function](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/functions.html#a-first-function-definition) and call it until guessed from main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(1): 
    print word_2  
    #Letting the person guess the word/ letter   
    guess_number = int(raw_input("choose a number:  "))
    guess_letter = raw_input("choose a letter:  ")

    i = word.index(guess_letter)
    if word_2[i] == guess_number:
        word_2[i] = guess_letter # put guessed letter into word_2, for example "3 A 20"
        print "Correct: ", word_2
        if word == word_2:
            break
    else:
        print "Nope"
    print "continue guessing"
```